# Ruby on Rails regexp equals-tilde vs. array include for checking a list of options

Tags: ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using Rails 3.2.3 with Ruby 1.9.3p0.

I'm finding that I often have to determine whether a string occurs in a list of options. It seems I can use the Ruby array [`.include` method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-include-3F):

```
<% if ['todo','pending','history'].include?(params[:category]) %>
```

or the regular expression [equals-tilde match shorthand](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#method-i-3D-7E) with vertical bars separating options:

```
<% if params[:category] =~ /todo|pending|history/ %>
```

Is one better than the other in terms of performance?

Is there an even better approach?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Summary**: *`Array#include?` with `String` elements wins for both accepted and rejected inputs, for your example with only three acceptable values. For a larger set to check, it looks like `Set#include?` with `String` elements might win.*

---

**How to Test**

We should test this is empirically.

Here are a couple of alternatives that you may want to consider as well: pre-compiled regex, a list of symbols, and a `Set` with `String` elements.

I would imagine that the performance may also depend on whether most of your inputs fall into the expected set, and are accepted, or whether most are outside the set, and are rejected.

Here's an empirical test script:

```
require 'benchmark'
require 'set'

strings = ['todo','pending','history']
string_set = Set.new(strings)
symbols = strings.map(&:to_sym)
regex_compiled = Regexp.new(strings.join("|"))

strings_avg_size = (strings.map(&:size).inject {|sum, n| sum + n}.to_f / strings.size).to_i
num_inputs = 1_000_000

accepted_inputs = (0...num_inputs).map { strings[rand(strings.size)] } 
rejected_inputs = (0...num_inputs).map { (0..strings_avg_size).map { ('a'...'z').to_a[rand(26)] }.join }

Benchmark.bmbm(40) do |x|
  x.report("Array#include?, Strings, accepted:") { accepted_inputs.map {|s| strings.include?(s) } }
  x.report("Array#include?, Strings, rejected:") { rejected_inputs.map {|s| strings.include?(s) } }
  x.report("Array#include?, Symbols, accepted:") { accepted_inputs.map {|s| symbols.include?(s.to_sym) } }
  x.report("Array#include?, Symbols, rejected:") { rejected_inputs.map {|s| symbols.include?(s.to_sym) } }
  x.report("Set#include?, Strings, accepted:") { accepted_inputs.map {|s| string_set.include?(s) } }
  x.report("Set#include?, Strings, rejected:") { rejected_inputs.map {|s| string_set.include?(s) } }
  x.report("Regexp#match, interpreted, accepted:") { accepted_inputs.map {|s| s =~ /todo|pending|history/ } }
  x.report("Regexp#match, interpreted, rejected:") { rejected_inputs.map {|s| s =~ /todo|pending|history/ } }
  x.report("Regexp#match, compiled, accepted:") { accepted_inputs.map {|s| regex_compiled.match(s) } }
  x.report("Regexp#match, compiled, rejected:") { rejected_inputs.map {|s| regex_compiled.match(s) } }
end
```

---

**Results**

```
Rehearsal ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Array#include?, Strings, accepted:        0.210000   0.000000   0.210000 (  0.215099)
Array#include?, Strings, rejected:        0.530000   0.010000   0.540000 (  0.543898)
Array#include?, Symbols, accepted:        0.330000   0.000000   0.330000 (  0.337767)
Array#include?, Symbols, rejected:        1.870000   0.050000   1.920000 (  1.923155)
Set#include?, Strings, accepted:          0.270000   0.000000   0.270000 (  0.274774)
Set#include?, Strings, rejected:          0.460000   0.000000   0.460000 (  0.463925)
Regexp#match, interpreted, accepted:      0.380000   0.000000   0.380000 (  0.382060)
Regexp#match, interpreted, rejected:      0.650000   0.000000   0.650000 (  0.660775)
Regexp#match, compiled, accepted:         1.130000   0.080000   1.210000 (  1.220970)
Regexp#match, compiled, rejected:         0.630000   0.000000   0.630000 (  0.640721)
------------------------------------------------------------------ total: 6.600000sec

                                              user     system      total        real
Array#include?, Strings, accepted:        0.210000   0.000000   0.210000 (  0.219060)
Array#include?, Strings, rejected:        0.430000   0.000000   0.430000 (  0.444911)
Array#include?, Symbols, accepted:        0.340000   0.000000   0.340000 (  0.341970)
Array#include?, Symbols, rejected:        1.080000   0.000000   1.080000 (  1.089961)
Set#include?, Strings, accepted:          0.270000   0.000000   0.270000 (  0.281270)
Set#include?, Strings, rejected:          0.400000   0.000000   0.400000 (  0.406181)
Regexp#match, interpreted, accepted:      0.370000   0.000000   0.370000 (  0.366931)
Regexp#match, interpreted, rejected:      0.560000   0.000000   0.560000 (  0.558652)
Regexp#match, compiled, accepted:         0.920000   0.000000   0.920000 (  0.915914)
Regexp#match, compiled, rejected:         0.620000   0.000000   0.620000 (  0.627620)
```

---

**Conclusions**

(see the Summary above)

It makes sense to me, upon reflection, that the Array of Symbols would be very slow for rejected inputs, because every single one of those random strings must be interned in the Symbol table before the check can be made.

It makes less sense to me, even after pondering, that the compiled Regexp would perform so badly, especially compared to the Regexp interpreted as a literal in the code. Can anyone explain why it does so badly?

Comment: Wow! Thanks. Your Ruby skills are way ahead of mine. Am  I reading this right? Do the numbers actually represent 1,000,000 tests? So even the slowest option takes 1.0899 seconds for 1,000,000 tests oor an average of 0.000001889 seconds per test? If it's really that fast, then I'm thinking that for day-to-day use in controllers and views, where there may only a couple of these `if` statements, I can just choose whichever seems most readable (the regex, IMO).

Comment: @MarkBerry thanks for the compliment. I like that Ruby makes it so easy to answer these questions. I agree that, for a small set of allowed options, it's going to be noise in your performance, so use what looks best. However, if you have a lot of allowed strings, you'll eventually need to use Set#include for performance, I'm pretty sure.

Answer (score 1):

@ms-tg's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11907146/624590) has good benchmarks, and answers your question well as far as I'm concerned. I just wanted to add a small note: be careful with this because these two options won't always have the same results:

```
params = Hash.new
keyword_array = ['todo','pending','history']  
included = nil

params[:category] = "history plus other text" 

start_time = Time.now
1000.times do
   included = keyword_array.include?(params[:category])
end
puts "Array.include? returned #{included} in #{(Time.now - start_time)*1000}ms"    
start_time = Time.now
1000.times do
   included = (params[:category] =~ /todo|pending|history/).is_a?(Integer) 
end
puts "Regexp returned #{included} in #{(Time.now - start_time)*1000}ms"
```

Returns:

> Array.include? returned false in 0.477ms
>
> Regexp returned true in 0.953ms

Notice that the regular expression returned **true** in this case, but the array.include? returned **false**. This should be considered when building your logic.

Basically, if the string isn't in the array exactly, array.include? will be false, but if one of the keywords is anywhere in the string the regular expression will be true (regardless of whether there's other text).

Comment: Good point, thanks:  as written, the regex is doing a "contains substring" search. Would this fix that (though sacrificing some readability): `/^todo$|^pending$|^history$/` ?. Re. the test results, your interpreted regex inclusion test takes 0.953ms for 1000 tests which would be 0.953 seconds for a million tests. @ms-tg's corresponding test was 0.366931 seconds for a million tests, so the same order of magnitude, and both pretty darn fast!

Comment: @MarkBerry, you could also do `/^(word|another|third)$/`, but again at the cost of a little readability.